# Undefined variable or method 'config' for main:Object in application.rb for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have come here as a last resort.  I can't find a solution anywhere else on the internet.  Thanks very much for your help.  I am creating an application in rails 4, and I am loosely following along an old tutorial, which can be found here https://github.com/schneems/reddit_on_rails

When I try to run

```
rails generate devise user
```

I get this error message:

```
config/application.rb:25:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method    

`config' for main:Object (NameError)
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in  

`require'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in   

`preload'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in 

`serve'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in   

`block in run'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in 

`loop'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in 

`<top (required)>'
from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext

/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext  

/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is my application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Stonedandalone
class Application < Rails::Application
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Recordauto-convert        

to  this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto  

loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false


#The last line is the one that caused the error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the `config` line up a few lines, to be inside of the class: `class Application < Rails::Application`.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer then to resolve the question.